# Is `nModified` from mongodb WriteResult a reliable indicator of update result?

Tags: mongodb, transactions

As far as I know only transactions guarantee complete update of multiple documents that is after invoking `updateMany` I expect mongo to have updated all of them. Without transactions some documents maybe updated immediately but some may be queued depending on mongodb load.

So I'm wondering what is the purpose of `nModified` from [WriteResult](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/) when not using transactions? If my update matched 100 documents but `nModified` is 50 maybe all it means that another 50 documents will be updated soon.

Answer (score 0):

[WriteResult.nModified](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/#WriteResult.nModified) indicates the number of existing documents *modified* by a write operation (in your case it is an update operation).

Using your example, if your update query matched 100 documents, but `nModified` returns only 50, that means the other 50 are unaffected by your update operation. This could mean that you're trying to set a value for field(s) that is equal to its current value (no point in updating).

Please note that there is also [write concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/) option that you could specify as part of [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#definition) options. `w:1` is the default write concern for MongoDB (as of v4.2)